# Why don't node-sass generated CSS files load on the first GET request?

Tags: css, node.js, web-applications, express, sass

I have a node express app that I wanted to have sass support for the css.  When I do a get on `http://myhost.com:port/css/whatever.css`, a `whatever.css` gets generated in the express_app_root/public/css directory as expected, with the *.scss source files in the express_app_root/sass directory.

The problem is, the browser doesn't load the css file.  It only loads it on the second request.  How can I have it both generate and load the css file on the first GET?

Here's the code that loads and configures node-sass:

```
var sass = require("node-sass");

...

app.use(sass.middleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'sass'),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'),
    prefix:  '/css',
    debug: true
}),express.static('/css',path.join(__dirname, '/public')) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's possible you may be loading your middleware out of order. Try moving your sass app.use() higher up, and see if that makes a difference...

Comment: Moved the app.use to immediately after the `var app = express();` declaration.  Now it works fine :)